# Initialization of external variables in C

Tags: c

I am a newbie to C. I was reading the book by Kernighan & Ritchie and found that external variables must be initialized only with constant expressions. Why is it so? Can you explain me what happens internally? When are they initialized? Why can't we initialize an external variable using those defined before it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link maybe give you better explaination. 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/

They have a explaination I quote below:

```
extern int var = 0;
int main(void)
{
 var = 10;
 return 0;
}
```

> Analysis: Guess this program will work? Well, here comes another
>   surprise from C standards. They say that..if a variable is only
>   declared and an initializer is also provided with that declaration,
>   then the memory for that variable will be allocated i.e. that variable
>   will be considered as defined. Therefore, as per the C standard, this
>   program will compile successfully and work.

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 1):

According to **C99 Standard: Section 6.7.8:**

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

And external variables have static storage duration, so it must be initialized by constant expressions or string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Any object with static storage duration such as variables declared outside of a function or variables inside a function declared as static can only be initialized with constant values.

The basic reason for this is that executable statements can't be placed outside of a function.

If such objects are not explicitly initialized then they are initialized to zero for arithmetic types or the null pointer for pointer types.

The common implementation is for values assigned to objects with static storage duration to be written directly into the executable image as data and loaded with the program image.